# Responsive Issues - Media Queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to align everything on my Bootstrap codes using media queries however it won't just work.

1. Here's what it looks like on 768px viewport. As you can see there is no space on right side.

[image]
2. Here's what it looks like on 768px viewport. The fieldset are too small.

[image]

Here's my markup:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="contactform">
         <fieldset class="form-group row">
            <input name="name" type="text" class="contact col-md-6" placeholder="Your Name *" >
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset class="form-group row">
            <input name="email" type="email" class="contact col-md-6" placeholder="E-mail address *" >
           </fieldset>

           <fieldset class="form-group row">
            <textarea name="comment" class="contact col-md-12" placeholder="Message *"></textarea>
          </fieldset>

           <button type="submit" id="submit" class="contact submit">Send message</button>
        </form>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {

input.contact.col-md-6{
    width:40.5%;
    margin: 15px 15px 0 58px;
}

textarea.contact.col-md-12 {
     margin: 15px 15px 0 58px;
}

button#submit.contact.submit{
    margin: 15px 15px 0 42px;
}

}
```

Any idea????

Comment: Yeah it is fine responsive means the fields gets shrinks according to screen size.

Comment: What is the issue? Can you show me some codes?

Comment: I'm no fan of any HTML framework, but you should just use max-width + padding or width % + margin auto to have equal horizontal spacing, then set everything inside that element to 100% width, I notice you are obsess with margins with px value which I believe a very bad practice for responsive coding. :)

Comment: How can you show me some codes that I can try? to see where did i go wrong?

Comment: @RodelGarcia your Markup is not upto *bootstrap* grid-system, as better layout should be like this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/zct7sqqo)

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: Checking on that.

Comment: Is that Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Well I need bootstrap 4 version of this.

Comment: Is it the same like this? http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/